# Error Code: 1054. Unknown clumn 'articletitle' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

I have read several different threads none of which really contained any helpful information pertaining to my problem. I've created a database in MySql Workbench and have it connected to a WinSCP HTLM/Java/PHP website. I'm trying to insert a list of data into the Workbench but I'm getting the error code 1054 message.

```
use CSC272_MKP;

drop table if exists articletable;

create table articletable 
(    id int primary key,
     articletitle TEXT,
     articleauthor varchar(255),
     yeararticlepublished mediumint, 
     resourcetypearticle mediumint
);

insert into articletable (articletitle, articleauthor, yeararticlepublished, resourcetypearticle) values ("tellus. Aenean","Miriam K. Stout",1926,999),("cursus,","Ira S. Fry",1935,999),("pellentesque","Macey H. Hawkins",1930,999),("eget metus. In","Marah U. Mccoy",1995,999),("primis in faucibus","Serena P. Sweet",1969,999),("aliquam","Stephen M. Sheppard",1923,999),("Nulla eu neque","Charde Y. Gill",1973,999),("id, ante.","Portia U. Woodard",1909,999),("at,","Kennedy J. Duke",1969,999),("quis","Imogene J. Mejia",1987,999),("quam dignissim","Mikayla J. Pierce",1996,999),("elementum sem,","Duncan Q. Henson",1938,999),("quam, elementum at,","Kareem G. Dickerson",1940,999),("elit","Heather T. Knox",1993,999),("felis","Hector I. Burnett",1990,999),("malesuada fames ac","Samson O. Miranda",1980,999),("ad","Mariam V. Wilkins",1926,999),("Sed","Brian X. Reese",1937,999),("Donec est. Nunc","Sebastian Z. Guerrero",1941,999),("neque sed sem","Jade N. Harper",1911,999),("Nam ligula elit,","Rina U. Bird",1995,999),("Duis","Judah T. Fulton",1901,999),("dolor. Fusce feugiat.","Hammett I. Rivas",1930,999),("vulputate, nisi","Barclay O. Chase",1961,999),("mauris","Jolene P. Russell",1958,999),("Donec","Hanae R. Hanson",1929,999),("a neque. Nullam","Naomi E. Allison",1906,999),("mattis","Clark G. Carroll",1918,999),("Integer","Tyler V. Simon",1919,999),("velit","Pandora N. Boyle",1918,999),("nascetur ridiculus mus.","Ivy M. Blair",2002,999),("turpis. Nulla aliquet.","Jolene Y. Reeves",1918,999),("cursus","Thaddeus N. Drake",1931,999),("pretium et,","Kim U. Horn",1903,999),("magnis dis parturient","Armand G. Mccray",1997,999),("Aliquam nisl.","Malcolm Z. Best",1922,999),("Integer eu lacus.","Pamela W. Conley",1930,999),("mauris. Integer sem","Roth B. Gillespie",1948,999),("non lorem vitae","Lael C. Boyer",1942,999),("at, iaculis quis,","Cadman F. Puckett",1915,999),("vitae","Keegan K. Mayo",1907,999),("arcu. Vestibulum","Jocelyn M. Mooney",1904,999),("Etiam","Gil B. Wooten",1981,999),("nisi. Aenean eget","Maite S. Whitney",1962,999),("molestie","Demetrius H. Kemp",1969,999),("tempus risus.","Priscilla H. Mcintosh",1995,999),("dolor. Fusce mi","Brock U. Wynn",1915,999),("enim. Suspendisse aliquet,","Hollee I. Koch",1967,999),("Integer aliquam adipiscing","Kermit G. Woodard",1926,999),("diam","Grant Z. Browning",1935,999),("malesuada","Natalie J. Boone",1955,999),("ligula","Darius U. Vance",1936,999),("sollicitudin","Maya X. Ryan",1908,999),("nonummy ac,","Joseph F. Raymond",1912,999),("Pellentesque","Davis B. Cervantes",2008,999),("neque vitae semper","Ori I. Kidd",1910,999),("Quisque varius.","Joy J. Roth",1934,999),("sem eget","Alden Y. Forbes",1928,999),("mauris. Suspendisse aliquet","Blaine Y. Chapman",2001,999),("ornare, elit elit","Ryan A. Mendez",1934,999),("ligula","Uriah U. Hale",1961,999),("tincidunt","Xavier X. Bradley",1955,999),("inceptos","Isabella E. Gonzalez",1953,999),("In","Charde I. Franklin",1952,999),("arcu imperdiet","Azalia J. Obrien",1914,999),("Maecenas ornare","Christine Z. Brewer",1957,999),("Morbi","Dexter T. Melendez",1927,999),("Cras sed leo.","Alfreda M. Shaw",2004,999),("eu","Mary U. Shelton",1973,999),("congue,","Juliet J. Padilla",1960,999),("magna. Cras","Ishmael W. Cortez",1905,999),("penatibus","Russell B. Dennis",2000,999),("ridiculus mus. Proin","Uriah M. Pate",1983,999),("neque pellentesque massa","Cassandra X. Diaz",1939,999),("porttitor interdum. Sed","Rae R. Weiss",1917,999),("Morbi non sapien","Ori K. Watson",1901,999),("auctor","Larissa Z. Campos",1910,999),("dui quis accumsan","Leilani Q. Terry",1932,999),("pede, malesuada vel,","Ursa F. Hanson",1908,999),("sed pede nec","Ina O. Avila",1981,999),("ac","Elton L. Hansen",1943,999),("lacinia.","Skyler N. Morton",1914,999),("eleifend","Hanna H. Stokes",1973,999),("eu","Martin P. Mcdaniel",1996,999),("primis","Ryder X. Bruce",1936,999),("felis.","Gillian K. Holmes",1992,999),("ut eros","Jenna E. Livingston",1939,999),("aliquet. Phasellus","Clarke Z. Ruiz",1903,999),("Duis risus","Iliana G. Harrington",1959,999),("sed,","Randall J. Brennan",1911,999),("non,","Meghan Y. Eaton",1975,999),("luctus ut, pellentesque","Jessica V. Nash",1948,999),("convallis est, vitae","Brooke V. Sellers",1954,999),("aliquet libero.","Hasad T. Noble",1942,999),("amet ornare","Risa T. Holcomb",1900,999),("Fusce fermentum fermentum","Briar E. Washington",1948,999),("non, lobortis","Malik R. Ward",1971,999),("Cras pellentesque.","Rafael V. Sears",1930,999),("adipiscing ligula. Aenean","Briar B. Stanton",1944,999),("augue scelerisque","Stone K. Barry",1976,999);

select * from articletable;
```

Any help or ideas would be appreciated. Apologies if this is a redundant question but I couldn't find help anywhere.

Comment: I dont see any issues with this. Can you please create a fiddle to demonstrate the issue? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

Running your SQL I've got an error related with `id` column:

[image: Error during SQL execution]

That's because you've created your table with an (primary key) `id` column but you forgot to set it as an auto increment column.

Once you set the  `id` column as auto increment you'll be able to insert new records on table:

[image: Inserted rows on Table]

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your SQL is that the field "id" is a primary key but it is not auto incremented.

You should add this after the creation:

```
ALTER TABLE `articletable` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

The last thing I can advise here is the use of "`" around every field name in the insert like this

```
INSERT INTO `articletable` (`articletitle`, `articleauthor`, `yeararticlepublished`, `resourcetypearticle`)
```